# Reset form field to Initial State on submit with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to reset my form fields to blank when a button is pressed.  For some reason its not working.
Here is my sample code:

initialize:

```
function App() {
  const [textField, setTextField] = useState("");
```

Clear the state:

```
  const clearState = () => {
    setTextField('');
  }
```

On submit:

```
  const submitForm = () => {
    clearState();
  };
```

Form field:

```
        <Form.Group controlId="textField">
          <Form.Control placeholder="Description" onChange={handleTextFieldInput} />
        </Form.Group>
```

But when I submit, the value is still the same as was input.

Comment: Have you tried setting value={textField} on the Form.Control?

Comment: That works, if you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `value={textField}` on the `Form.Control`, that should fix it :)